# Salesforce error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, salesforce, omniauth

I tried login functionality using 'omnioauth-salesforce' used salesforce developer login , i have mention the callback `http://localhost:3000/auth/salesforce/callback` inside connected app

in my devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :salesforce, "consumer_id","consumer_secret"
```

when i click login link `/users/auth/salesforce/`
i have getting this error

> error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration

Comment: now it's work to changed callback `http://localhost:3000/auth/salesforce/callback` replaced this `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/salesforce/callback`

Comment: Even I am facing same problem now, where is this url reading from? http://localhost:3000/users/auth/salesforce/callback. If it is another local url what needs to be there in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to include `REDIRECT_URI` as a query param  in your authorization/login redirection URL and that it is the same as mentioned in the connected app.

Answer (score -1):

You are using localhost:3000 in your connected app for callback url in salesforce. It will not work because salesforce does not recognize localhost of your local pc. You should use static ip like

"https://112.167.1.64" instead of "https://localhost:3000".